# How to authenticate when using VideoPlayer?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-glass, google-gdk

I am implementing the following solution [Play a video in Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21671044)

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER");
i.putExtra("video_url", "..."); 
startActivity(i);
```

But I am getting hit with a 401 error.

To authenticate I need to include my key/value pair in header.

How do I go about doing that, with intents?

```
10-16 14:58:55.229    126-10199/? I/ChromiumHTTPDataSourceSupport﹕ Server responded with http status 401
10-16 14:58:55.229    126-10470/? I/AwesomePlayer﹕ mConnectingDataSource->connect() returned -1004
10-16 14:58:55.229  10175-10216/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1004)
10-16 14:58:55.237  10175-10197/? W/VideoPlayer﹕ Failed to start playback.
    java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
            at com.google.glass.videoplayer.VideoPlayer$4.serialDoInBackground(SourceFile:577)
            at com.google.glass.videoplayer.VideoPlayer$4.serialDoInBackground(SourceFile:463)
            at com.google.glass.async.SerialAsyncTask.doInBackground(SourceFile:59)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:302)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at com.google.glass.async.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(SourceFile:39)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER` Intent is an undocumented Intent that is likely to change without any notice. There's no official support for it, thus no authentication.

If you need video playback capability, I strongly recommend that you follow this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=594).

Comment: The link you provided is for playing a local video. I wish to play a video from a url, and authenticate. Any way to do you that?

Comment: @Alain Will this intent ever be documented in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Hi prepare method of mediaplayer fails if you call it before setting the datasource or if setdatasource fails
Try changing the url

Answer (score 0):

Currently (only for testing) I made the token a query parameter, and authenticated through that.