# What is the best way to auto play YouTube videos on Glass?

Tags: youtube, google-glass

I need a way to automatically play a YouTube video on my Google Glass. I tried the Youtube JS API but after .playVideo() the video doesn't play, it only shows a black screen. I tried embed the video with the autoplay function but it doesn't autoplay. I can play embedded videos only when I click the play button myself.

Is there a simple way to (auto)play a youtube video full screen?

Comment: You are able to successfully play embedded videos on Glass through the YouTube JS API? Documentation states that that particular API requires Flash Player to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have full control over the video player, you can use the **YouTube Android Player API**.
You can find more info [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

You'll have to:

- Download the API client library
- Register your application through the Google APIs console
- Setup the library and integrate the `YoutubePlayer` in your `Activity`

Take a look at the demo, and especially at the `FullscreenDemoActivity`.

**Edit:** A simpler method would be to use this Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER");
i.putExtra("video_url", "https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx"); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: As mentioned in an answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412290/how-to-authenticate-when-using-videoplayer), "com.google.glass.action.VIDEOPLAYER is an undocumented intent that is likely to change without any notice. There's no official support for it..." Please do keep that in mind.